# Add web font (FoundIcons) inside input text element

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I would like to add an icon (magnifying-glass) inside an input box used for site content searching.
Something like that: http://webnus2.net/florida/ (top menu)
I don't need the animation logic: this is something I know how to do.

Of course want to use FoundIcons and I'm using Foundation 5.

I suppose I could use some trick by putting the correct character in the placeholder attribute, but I prefer to simply use CSS.

Anyone has some tips to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a placeholder and style it accordingly to display your FoundIcon.

```
<input type="text" class="search-text-box" id="search-box" style="width: 140px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);" placeholder="&#61486;">
```

and style it:

```
.search-text-box {
    font-family: 'GeneralFoundicons'; /* This is for the placeholder */
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 7px 5px 8px 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 1px;        
}
```

it's important to use the font family `GeneralFoundicons` to display the FoundIcon ad placeholder, to get the correct decimal value and set it in the placeholder attribute you must check the css file and convert the HEX value into DEC eg:

> (HEXvalue = \f02e) converts to (Decimal = 61486)

alternatively you can use a wrapping element to show your icon:

```
<i class="general foundicon-search"><input type="text" class="search-text-box" id="search-box2" style="width: 140px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);"/></i>
```

Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ksh69/

Comment: Thanks @irvin-dominin-aka-edward: the placeholder is the solution I was looking for. I actually considered this solution before asking, but I thought this would have messed up the font used inside the input box). Instead it works perfectly (and to be honest I'm not sure how it doesn't affect the look of wherever is entered by the user).

Comment: @AndreaSciamanna Your are welcome, and italian like me too :-) I think because if exist is used the web font and the other text in the appropriate font (inherited or default), but I can't find any official doc

Answer (score 0):

In your css class:

```
background-image: url("Your image path");
background-position: "x" "unit" "y" "unit";
background-repeat: "sequence";
```

Example:

```
background-image: url(../images/search-icon.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat
```

Comment: Maybe you've missed the "FoundIcons" part :) I don't want to use an image, but a font icon.

Comment: You're free to look around but I don't think that's possible :p. And you're making your own life difficult.